# Criar splash screen na aplicação Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Preciso criar uma espécie de Splash Screen para uma aplicação no Electron.
A organização ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
Inicialização do App;
Abrir a splashWindow (uma página frameless) por 3 segundos;
Abrir a mainWindow normalmente.
```

Lembrando que a mainWindow puxa o link do http://web.whatsapp.com/ então não tenho acesso à página em si. A splashWindow é local.

Existe algum tipo de contador de segundos no Electron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deve fazer algo do género.

Primeiro a tela principal deve estar oculta.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
     width: 1200,
     height: 800,
     show: false
 })
```

A seguir criar e mostra uma nova janela para o Splash

```
var splash = new BrowserWindow({ width: 500, height: 300 });
```

Assim que a app estiver pronta para arrancar. Pode usar um simples `setTimeout`:

```
 mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        splash.close();
        mainWindow.show();
    }, 3000);
})
```